Keyboard Automatically Opens and Closes in Textfield within Dialog
I've encountered a perplexing issue in my Flutter application. Despite reviewing similar posts on Stack Overflow and attempting suggested solutions, I've been unable to resolve the problem.
In my app, I have a dialog containing a textfield where users can input text. However, when attempting to type in the textfield, the keyboard opens (as expected) but it closes on its own immediately after opening, preventing users from entering their desired value.

Interestingly, this problem arises exclusively on devices running recent versions of Android (e.g., Samsung Galaxy S23), and it only manifests after transitioning to Flutter SDK '>=3.2.6 <4.0.0'.
Notably, this problem was absent even on smartphones with recent Android versions when using SDK '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
I'm uncertain whether the problem stems from differences in Android versions between devices or if there's an error in my code.
Here's my current implementation:
Future<void> _bondDevice(device) async {
    final pinValueController = TextEditingController();

    SharedPreferences storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    bool isInputEmpty = true;

    bool isChecked = false;
    bool passwordVisible = false;

    if (!widget.isAndroidPlatform) {
      return;
    }

    bleBondingKey = storage.getString(_keyBondingCode);

    if ((bleBondingKey == null) || (bleBondingKey != null && isBonded == -1)) {
      isBondingDialogOpen = true;

      if (!context.mounted) return;

      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Bluetooth pairing request'),
                  content: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                            "Enter the bonding key to pair with ${device.id.toString()} (Try 0000 or 1234)."),
                        TextField(
                          autofocus: true,
                          obscureText: !passwordVisible,
                          controller: pinValueController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Bonding Key",
                            focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF635F5F)),
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                passwordVisible
                                    ? Icons.visibility
                                    : Icons.visibility_off,
                                color: Colors.grey[800],
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                // Update the state i.e. toggle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                setState(() {
                                  passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              if (pinValueController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                //add these lines
                                isInputEmpty = false;
                              } else {
                                isInputEmpty = true;
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            const Text("Remember"),
                            Checkbox(
                                activeColor: kThemeColor,
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 2, color: kThemeColor),
                                value: isChecked,
                                onChanged: (checked) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isChecked = checked!;
                                  });
                                })
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      child: const Text("Cancel",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: kThemeColor,
                          )),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: isInputEmpty
                          ? null
                          : () async {
                              var value = pinValueController.value;
                              var key = value.text;

                              if (isChecked) {
                                await storage.setString(_keyBondingCode, key);
                              }

                              var pin = value.text;
                              if (!context.mounted) return;
                              Navigator.pop(context, pin);
                            },
                      child: Text("Send",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: isInputEmpty ? Colors.grey : kThemeColor,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
          }).then((pin) async {
        if (pin != null) {
          setState(() {
            isBonded = 1;
          });
          bonded = (await fbs.FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
              .bondDeviceAtAddress(device.id.toString(), pin: pin))!;
          getBondingResult(bonded);
        }
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isBonded = 1;
      });
      bonded = (await fbs.FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
          .bondDeviceAtAddress(device.id.toString(), pin: bleBondingKey))!;
      getBondingResult(bonded);
    }
  }

This is the complete code:
class DeviceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DeviceScreen(
      {super.key,
      required this.device,
      required this.asnConfig,
      required this.isAndroidPlatform});

  final BluetoothDevice device;
  final String asnConfig;
  final bool isAndroidPlatform;

  @override
  State<DeviceScreen> createState() => _DeviceScreenState();
}

class _DeviceScreenState extends State<DeviceScreen> {
  bool isSendingToTheServer = false;
  int isBonded = 0;

  final String _keyBondingCode = 'bondingKey';

  String? bleBondingKey;

  bool snackBarShowed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkIfAlreadyBonded(widget.device);
  }

  late bool bonded = false;
  bool isBondingDialogOpen = false;
  bool servicesAreAlreadyShowed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: Text(widget.device.name,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: kThemeColor,
        actions: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
            stream: widget.device.state,
            initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
            builder: (c, snapshot) {
              VoidCallback? onPressed;
              String text;
              bool connected;
              switch (snapshot.data) {
                case BluetoothDeviceState.connected:
                  onPressed = () {
                    widget.device.disconnect();
                  };
                  text = 'DISCONNECT';
                  connected = true;
                  discoverServices();
                  if ((connected && isBonded == 0) ||
                      ((isBonded == -1) && (!isBondingDialogOpen))) {
                    if ((isBonded != 1) && (!isBondingDialogOpen)) {
                      _bondDevice(widget.device);
                    }
                  }
                  break;
                case BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected:
                  onPressed = () {
                    widget.device.connect();
                    if (isBonded != 2) {
                      _bondDevice(widget.device);
                    }
                  };
                  text = 'CONNECT';
                  connected = false;
                  break;
                default:
                  onPressed = null;
                  text = snapshot.data.toString().substring(21).toUpperCase();
                  connected = false;
                  break;
              }
              return Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: isSendingToTheServer && connected
                        ? const Icon(Icons.hourglass_top_rounded,
                            color: Colors.white)
                        : const Icon(Icons.cloud_upload_outlined,
                            color: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (widget.isAndroidPlatform) {
                        if (connected && isBonded == 2) {
                          setState(() {
                            isSendingToTheServer = true;
                          });
                          setState(() {
                            SendDeviceInformation()
                                .sendDeviceInfoToTheServer(
                                    context, widget.device)
                                .then((_) {
                              setState(() {
                                isSendingToTheServer = false;
                              });
                            });
                          });
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                              content: Text(
                                  "The device should be connected and bonded first")));
                        }
                      } else {
                        if (connected) {
                          setState(() {
                            isSendingToTheServer = true;
                          });
                          setState(() {
                            SendDeviceInformation()
                                .sendDeviceInfoToTheServer(
                                    context, widget.device)
                                .then((_) {
                              setState(() {
                                isSendingToTheServer = false;
                              });
                            });
                          });
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text(
                                      "The device should be connected first")));
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: onPressed,
                      child: Text(
                        text,
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .primaryTextTheme
                            .labelLarge
                            ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                ],
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
              stream: widget.device.state,
              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                String bondingStatus;
                switch (isBonded) {
                  case 2:
                    bondingStatus = 'bonded';
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    bondingStatus = 'bonding is in process...';
                    break;
                  default:
                    bondingStatus = 'not bonded';
                }

                return ListTile(
                  leading: (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected)
                      ? const Icon(Icons.bluetooth_connected)
                      : const Icon(Icons.bluetooth_disabled),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                              'Device is ${snapshot.data.toString().split('.')[1]} and $bondingStatus.'),
                          ShowDeviceMac(
                              mac: widget.device.id.toString(),
                              isAndroidPlatform: widget.isAndroidPlatform),
                          if (widget.isAndroidPlatform)
                            Text(
                              "MAC: ${widget.device.id}",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                            )
                        ]),
                  ),
                  trailing: StreamBuilder<bool>(
                    stream: widget.device.isDiscoveringServices,
                    initialData: false,
                    builder: (c, snapshot) => IndexedStack(
                      index: snapshot.data! ? 1 : 0,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                          onPressed: () => widget.device.discoverServices(),
                        ),
                        const IconButton(
                          icon: SizedBox(
                            width: 18.0,
                            height: 18.0,
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: null,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: widget.device.mtu,
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                title: const Text('MTU Size'),
                subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data} bytes'),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () => widget.device.requestMtu(223),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothService>>(
              stream: widget.device.services,
              initialData: const [],
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data?.isNotEmpty == true) {
                  String asnConfigDefString =
                      widget.asnConfig.replaceAll(r"\\", "");
                  var allJson = jsonDecode(asnConfigDefString);

                  var firmwareMappingsArray = allJson['firmwareMappings'];

                  if (firmwareMappingsArray != null &&
                      firmwareMappingsArray.length != 0) {
                    return Column(
                      children: _buildServiceTiles(snapshot.data!, context),
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  // Ensure you return a non-nullable value
                  return const Column();
                }
                if (!snackBarShowed) {
                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                          "The 'Asn Config Definition' configured in your user's attributes may be incorrect or outdated. Please reach out to Safectory for assistance in updating it."),
                    ));
                    snackBarShowed = true;
                  });
                }

                // Return a non-nullable value in case none of the conditions are met
                return const Column();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _bondDevice(device) async {
    final pinValueController = TextEditingController();

    SharedPreferences storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    bool isInputEmpty = true;

    bool isChecked = false;
    bool passwordVisible = false;

    if (!widget.isAndroidPlatform) {
      return;
    }

    bleBondingKey = storage.getString(_keyBondingCode);

    if ((bleBondingKey == null) || (bleBondingKey != null && isBonded == -1)) {
      isBondingDialogOpen = true;

      if (!context.mounted) return;

      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Bluetooth pairing request'),
                  content: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                            "Enter the bonding key to pair with ${device.id.toString()} (Try 0000 or 1234)."),
                        TextField(
                          autofocus: true,
                          obscureText: !passwordVisible,
                          controller: pinValueController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Bonding Key",
                            focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF635F5F)),
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                passwordVisible
                                    ? Icons.visibility
                                    : Icons.visibility_off,
                                color: Colors.grey[800],
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                // Update the state i.e. toggle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                setState(() {
                                  passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              if (pinValueController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                //add these lines
                                isInputEmpty = false;
                              } else {
                                isInputEmpty = true;
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            const Text("Remember"),
                            Checkbox(
                                activeColor: kThemeColor,
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 2, color: kThemeColor),
                                value: isChecked,
                                onChanged: (checked) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isChecked = checked!;
                                  });
                                })
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      child: const Text("Cancel",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: kThemeColor,
                          )),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: isInputEmpty
                          ? null
                          : () async {
                              var value = pinValueController.value;
                              var key = value.text;

                              if (isChecked) {
                                await storage.setString(_keyBondingCode, key);
                              }

                              var pin = value.text;
                              if (!context.mounted) return;
                              Navigator.pop(context, pin);
                            },
                      child: Text("Send",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: isInputEmpty ? Colors.grey : kThemeColor,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
          }).then((pin) async {
        if (pin != null) {
          setState(() {
            isBonded = 1;
          });
          bonded = (await fbs.FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
              .bondDeviceAtAddress(device.id.toString(), pin: pin))!;
          getBondingResult(bonded);
        }
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isBonded = 1;
      });
      bonded = (await fbs.FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
          .bondDeviceAtAddress(device.id.toString(), pin: bleBondingKey))!;
      getBondingResult(bonded);
    }
  }

  Future<void> checkIfAlreadyBonded(device) async {
    await fbs.FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
        .getBondedDevices()
        .then((listOfBondedDevices) async {
      if (listOfBondedDevices.isNotEmpty) {
        var foundResult = listOfBondedDevices
            .where((element) => element.address == device.id.toString());
        if (foundResult.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            isBonded = 2;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void getBondingResult(bonded) {
    if (bonded) {
      setState(() {
        isBonded = 2;
      });
    } else {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        setState(() {
          isBonded = -1;
        });
        widget.device.connect();
      });
    }
    isBondingDialogOpen = false;
  }

  List<Widget> _buildServiceTiles(
      List<BluetoothService> services, BuildContext context) {
    return services
        .where((result) {
          var serviceUUID =
              result.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8);
          return isAvailableForTheUser(
              serviceUUID, widget.asnConfig, widget.isAndroidPlatform);
        })
        .map(
          (s) => ServiceTile(
            service: s,
            characteristicTiles: s.characteristics
                .where((result) {
                  var characteristicUUID =
                      result.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8);
                  return isAvailableForTheUser(characteristicUUID,
                      widget.asnConfig, widget.isAndroidPlatform);
                })
                .map(
                  (c) => CharacteristicTile(
                    service: s,
                    asnConfig: widget.asnConfig,
                    macaddress: widget.device.id.toString(),
                    characteristic: c,
                    onReadPressed: () => c.read(),
                    onWritePressed: () async {
                      //write characteristic dialog
                      await showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return EditCharacteristicDialog(c);
                          });
                    },
                    /*onNotificationPressed: () async {
                      await c.setNotifyValue(!c.isNotifying);
                      await c.read();
                    },*/
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
      MaterialState.pressed,
      MaterialState.hovered,
      MaterialState.focused,
    };
    if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
      return Colors.blue;
    }
    return kThemeColor;
  }

  void discoverServices() {
    if (!servicesAreAlreadyShowed) {
      widget.device
          .discoverServices()
          .then((value) => servicesAreAlreadyShowed = true);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}

Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

This issues has been caused because there is autoFocus set to true so you should turn that off and keyboard won't open automatically.

I encountered this problem as well before enabling autoFocus to true. I had hoped that enabling autoFocus would resolve the issue. But in general I expect the keyboard to open, the problem is that it doesn't stay open.

Seems like the text field is getting the focus once the dialog opens --> leads to the keyboard to appear and loses it again --> leads to the keyboard to disappear
